# Unexpected results with jQuery-TokenInput pre-populated Data changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, jquery-tokeninput

I am getting unexpected results with [jQuery-TokenInput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) pre_populated data-set changes.
I have followed the [Railscasts - Token Fields](http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields) and updated the necessary code with [Railscasts - Token Fields Revised source code](https://github.com/railscasts/258-token-fields/tree/master/revised) acc. to the newest Rails version.

My coffeescript code that handles the token search query is:

`jQuery ->

    $('#user_tracker_ids').tokenInput '/trackers.json'

    prePopulate: $('#user_tracker_ids').data('load')

    minChars: 3

    hintText: "Type in name"

    preventDuplicates : true`

My Strange results are:

1. CASE 1: [*Initial case*][CORRECT]
   When the token-field is empty i.e no pre-populated data, and I enter any no. of tokens, I get the ID's associated with the tokens at my server-side action, which is correct.
2. CASE 2: [*Ending case* ][CORRECT]
   When I remove all the ID's entered before i.e I remove all the pre-populated data, I get `0` ids, which is also correct.
3. **CASE 3**: [***Failing case***][WRONG]
   When there are already values in the token-input, and I update them, e.g add more tokens, remove some of the existing tokens, I only get the ID's of the token's that were added in the current edit session. Changes made to the pre-populated data in the query-tokenInput are not sent to the server-side action.

I'm sure I'm missing some nitty-gritty setting here, but I'm unable to find it and fix it.
If you need more info. to locate the issue, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a mistake at my end, and a stupid one indeed.
`prePopulate: $('#user_tracker_ids').data('load')`

In the input to `prePopulate` call, the data being sent was incomplete. I was only passing the  **name** field for the objects and didn't pass the **id** field.

Hence, token-input was able to properly show the names for the pre-populated data, but any change made to it was not reflected, as I mentioned in my question above.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
                $(elementId).tokenInput("",
                {
                    prePopulate:JSON.parse(YourJsonFormatStringHere)
                });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found the mistake and now it's working properly. But I couldn't understand what your answer suggested.
Can you elaborate a bit on your answer.

Comment: This function converts jason string to object in asp.net